# Como instalar o VLC plugin no navegador?

Tags: html5-video, reprodutor-de-video, libvlc

Estou seguindo diversas paginas para tocar meu vídeo de exemplo no navegador, e estou tendo grandes dificuldades com o plugin VLC, pois simplesmente nao consigo instalar..

**Eis o vídeo de exemplo:**

```
http://dveo.com/downloads/TS-sample-files/San_Diego_Clip.ts
```

**Aqui o Código que estou usando para ativar o pluguin:**

> exemplo do SOpt:

```
<embed
  type="application/x-vlc-plugin"
  pluginspage="http://www.videolan.org"
  version="VideoLAN.VLCPlugin.2"
  width="300"
  height="200"
  id="vlc"
  loop="yes"
  autoplay="yes"
  target="http://dveo.com/downloads/TS-sample-files/San_Diego_Clip.ts"
/>
</embed>
```

> exemplo do VLC wiki:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <title>
    VLC Mozilla plugin test page
  </title>
  <body>
    <embed
      type="application/x-vlc-plugin"
      pluginspage="http://www.videolan.org"
      width="640"
      height="480"
      id="vlc"
      target="http://dveo.com/downloads/TS-sample-files/San_Diego_Clip.ts"
    />

    <script type="text/javascript">
      <!--
      var vlc = document.getElementById("vlc");
      vlc.audio.toggleMute();
      //-->
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

**MAS sempre aparece ""this plugin is not supported""**

Na configuração dos navegadores procurei  por vários Plugins VLC mas nenhum parece ser o correto, na pagina do VLC também Não  encontro para baixar / instalar...

Comment: Oi Camila, pode ser que o plugin esteja para 64bit e o navegador para x86 ou vice-versa, tem como dar mais detalhes?

Comment: Sim posso dar mais detalhes, mas entenda ... como sou novata nao sei bem como "falar", por favor me diga o que precisa...  ___1) Meu windows de teste eh 64Bits, assim como  o **chrome, mozila, safari, edge, explorer e vivaldi**..  ___2) tambem estou testando no ubuntu 64 com **chrome, mozila, safari e vivald**i ___3) e  tambem no MacOS sierra.. **com chrome, mozila, safari, edge, explorer e vivaldi....** ___4)    MAS EU NAO CONSEGUI  instalar o plugin em nenhum navegador... de nenhum SO

Comment: achoque o problema maior eh como "conferir" se o pluguin VLC esta **instalado**

Comment: Vou testar o VLC plugin e o Embed ou Video para ver se consigo reproduzir o problema ou resolve-lo e assim que conseguir lhe aviso, salvei sua pergunta nos favoritos para não esquecer.

Comment: OBRIGADAAA!  :D   eu realmente nao sei como INSTALAR  o plugin VLC no browser...